# How to integrate FBSDKCoreKit into a Swift custom Framework?

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods

Did anyone managed to integrate FBSDKCoreKit to a custom swift framework with cocoapods (or alternate method)?

When I do this (experiment 1):

```
target 'MyFramework' do
    project 'MyFrameWork/MyFramework.xcodeproject'
    pod 'FacebookSDK', :modular_headers => true
end

target 'MyApp' do
    workspace 'MyWorkspace.xcworkspace'
    project 'MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj'
    inherit! :complete

    target :MyAppTests
    target :MyAppUITests
end
```

I get `No such module 'FBSDKCoreKit'` when compiling the framework (same applies when setting `modular_headers => false`.

I have also tested `use_frameworks!` as follows: (experiment 2):

```
target 'MyFramework' do
    project 'MyFrameWork/MyFramework.xcodeproject'
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'FacebookSDK'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    workspace 'MyWorkspace.xcworkspace'
    project 'MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj'
    inherit! :complete

    target :MyAppTests
    target :MyAppUITests
end
```

But then I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Bolts.framework/Bolts
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/***/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
  Reason: image not found`.
```

Note: When I add the `FacebookSDK` to `MyApp` (with `use_frameworks!`) it works, but then, I can't make use of it from within `MyFramework` (hence useless to me).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found another way to do that, so I dropped Cocoapods.

I stumbled upon the fact that Facebook publishes a Swift package (https://swiftpackageregistry.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk).

So I proceeded as follows:

- removed `pod 'FacebookSDK'` from my pod file;
- added the above mentioned package for my framework.

And voila!